# Calculate sum of distances between nodes of a graph passed as an array in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph

Graph definition (The graph is fixed for the problem concerned):

N1 <---10---> N2 <---30---> N3 <---20---> N4

We assume that the distance of a node from itself will always be 0. The distance between two nodes will be the sum of their distances. The distance between two nodes is the value of the sum of the edges to get from one node to another in the defined graph.

```
| code     | other          | graph                           |
| -------- | -------------- |-------------------------------- |
| 01       | blue           | [N4, N2, N2]                    |
| 02       | red            | [N1, N2]                        |
| 03       | green          | [N1, N1]                        |
| 04       | white          | [N1, N3, N4]                    |
| 05       | blue           | [N3, N4, N1]                    |
| 06       | white          | [N1, N3, N2, N4, N4]            |
```

I want to add to the pandas DataFrame a new column called `distance` that calculates the distance done.

```
| code     | other          | graph                           | distance |
| -------- | -------------- |-------------------------------- | -------- |
| 01       | blue           | [N4, N2, N2]                    | 50       |
| 02       | red            | [N1, N2]                        | 10       |
| 03       | green          | [N1, N1]                        | 0        |
| 04       | white          | [N1, N3, N4]                    | 60       |
| 05       | blue           | [N3, N4, N1]                    | 80       |
| 06       | white          | [N1, N3, N2, N4, N4]            | 120      |
```

**Example from row code 06:**

sum = (**N1 -> N3**) + (**N3 -> N2**) + (**N2 -> N4**) + (**N4 -> N4**)

**N1 -> N3** = (N1 -> N2) + (N2 -> N3) = 10 + 30 = 40

**N3 -> N2** = 30

**N2 -> N4** = (N2 -> N3) + (N3 -> N4) = 30 + 20 = 50

**N4 -> N4** = 0

sum = 40 + 30 + 50 + 0 = 120

My ideas:

1. Store the adjacency matrix of the graph in the next DataFrame:

| node1 | node2 | distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N1 | N1 | 0 |
| N2 | N2 | 0 |
| N3 | N3 | 0 |
| N4 | N4 | 0 |
| N1 | N2 | 10 |
| N2 | N1 | 10 |
| N1 | N3 | 40 |
| N3 | N1 | 40 |
| N1 | N4 | 60 |
| N4 | N1 | 60 |
| N2 | N3 | 30 |
| N3 | N2 | 30 |
| N2 | N4 | 50 |
| N4 | N2 | 50 |
| N3 | N4 | 20 |
| N4 | N3 | 20 |

2. For each row of the DataFrame, extract the array from the `graph` column:

```
# Perhaps this is a very inefficient solution.
df['graph'] = df['graph'].apply(lambda x: get_distance(x['graph']), axis=1)
```

3. Define the `get_distance` function as follows:

```
def get_distance(row):
   # [N4, N2, N2]
   # iterate over the array and get the distance of each node pair
   # sum = 0
   # [N4, N2] -> 50 // sum += 50
   # [N2, N2] -> 0 // sum += 0
   return sum
```

Comment: Could you please mention, how do you store or calculate the distance between two nodes ?

Comment: The distance between two nodes is the value of the sum of the edges to get from one node to another in the defined graph: ```N1 <---10---> N2 <---30---> N3 <---20---> N4```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I suggest you build the adjacency matrix of your graph (manually or automatically, I don't know where your graph comes form), and then you iterate over the `graph` list and lookup entries in the adjacency matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach using [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html):

```
import networkx as nx

# init distances
distances = {("N1", "N2"): 10, ("N2", "N1"): 10, ("N2", "N3"): 30, ("N3", "N2"): 30, ("N3", "N4"): 20,
             ("N4", "N3"): 20}

# create the graph using the distances dict
G = nx.Graph()
for (start, end), length in distances.items():
    G.add_edge(start, end, length=length)

# compute the aggregated distance value
df["distance"] = df["graph"].apply(
    lambda e: sum(nx.shortest_path_length(G, s, t, weight='length') for s, t in zip(e, e[1:])))
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   code  other                 graph  distance
0     1   blue          [N4, N2, N2]        50
1     2    red              [N1, N2]        10
2     3  green              [N1, N1]         0
3     4  white          [N1, N3, N4]        60
4     5   blue          [N3, N4, N1]        80
5     6  white  [N1, N3, N2, N4, N4]       120
```

The answer assumes the column `df["graph"]` is a list of strings.